# Android OSS license plugin crash on tapping menu items

Tags: android, google-play-services, gms-licenses-plugin

I've been trying out the [Google APIs for Android OSS licenses](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource#how_licenses_are_determined) tool and come across an issue.

The activity is being launched from a library module that contains the preferences aspect to my app. However, the Play Services code is crashing a lot! Has anyone seen this upon tapping the found OSS list items?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oceanlife/com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Here are the actions leading to that action;

[image: replication]

Comment: Found that the fix is available with latest com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:16.0.0, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51394239/2231099

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Just specify appropriate theme in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file for 2 activities OssLicensesMenuActivity and OssLicensesActivity. For example:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesMenuActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"/>

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"/>
```

Comment: Ah man, you're right! Had completely removed the ````ActionBar```` -based app theme since ````Toolbar````s. Toolbars FTW and all that. Anyways, this was the problem. +1 and a tick.

Comment: Nice! It looks to me like the theme you use must (1) inherit from `Theme.AppCompat` and (2) have an action bar.

Answer (score 1):

**Application** tag

```
<application
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

application/>
```

and `styles.xml`

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>
```

I hope `ActionBar` required to set **Title** of activity

[image: Working like this]