# Theme for play-services-oss-licenses

Tags: android, open-source, android-appcompat

Is anyone successfully using the new play-services-oss-licenses library? When trying to use it as described here:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource

I get:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
>        You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
>        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:354)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:323)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.initWindowDecorActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:175)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:145)
>                                                                                 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
>                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesMenuActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:54)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
>                                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

I am using AppCompat in the rest of my app - and not setting a theme for this activity. Is this a bug in this library (this is what I think at the moment) - or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Post your Manifest

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124863/android-oss-license-plugin-crash-on-tapping-menu-items

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set the proper Theme for the activities in your case.

Add these Activity declarations in your AndroidManifest.xml

**Dark**

```
<activity 
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesMenuActivity"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />

<activity    
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesActivity"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

[image: Dark]

**Light**

```
<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesMenuActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

<activity
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
```

[image: Light]

Comment: Jetpack Compose uses MaterialTheme

Answer (score -2):

In case you haven't discovered this already, issue is fixed with plugin version

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:16.0.0`

You don't need to apply a theme with ActionBar since the plugin doesn't borrow the style from application anymore.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#july_12_2018

Comment: Looking at the code it looks like it is still using the app theme - it just won't crash anymore if you don't have an action bar.