# OSS license plugin crashes on starting OssLicensesMenuActivity

Tags: android, gms-licenses-plugin

Every one! I've included Android OSS using this tutorial [Google APIs for Android OSS licenses](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource#how_licenses_are_determined). into my project (target sdk version is 27).

But I have an issue when I starting **OssLicensesMenuActivity**.

I do this as follows:

```
OssLicensesMenuActivity.setActivityTitle("OSS Licenses Demo");
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), OssLicensesMenuActivity.class));
```

Here is issue:

```
ResourceType: For resource 0x7f07000a, entry index(10) is beyond type entryCount(4)
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:161)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f07000a
     at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourcePackageName(ResourcesImpl.java:248)
     at android.content.res.Resources.getResourcePackageName(Resources.java:2783)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdmw.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdmw.zzeq(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.zzb.loadInBackground(Unknown Source)
     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:306)
     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:59)
     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:47)
     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:138)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    ... 3 more
```

Also, I've tried to add [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124863/android-oss-license-plugin-crash-on-tapping-menu-items) to Manifest, but issue wasn't fixed:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesMenuActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"/>

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesActivity"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I've moved my project to Android Studio 3.0.1 (and as consequence Gradle was updated to version 3.0.1) the issue was fixed.

Comment: I have the gradle plugin 3.1.0 and it this did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into same issue with the following plugin dependency,

`com.google.gms:oss-licenses:0.9.2`

`com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:11.4.2`

Found that its fixed with latest `com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:16.0.0`. This required bumping `com.google.gms:google-services` to `3.2.1`  to resolve conflict with branched off firebase/play-services sdks.

Reference : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

[image]