# Why i'm getting error while adding OssLicensesMenuActivity

Tags: android, licensing

I am trying to add `OssLicensesMenuActivity` to my android project. I'm using this [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource)
While running I'm getting error `java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()`

```
02-06 14:47:36.192 3152-8300/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityStartTrigger: not whiteListedaabasoft.geomark/com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesMenuActivity/21
02-06 14:47:36.192 3152-8300/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedaabasoft.geomark/com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesMenuActivity/21
02-06 14:47:36.206 3152-12605/? E/ActivityTrigger: activityResumeTrigger: not whiteListedaabasoft.geomark/com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.OssLicensesMenuActivity/21
02-06 14:47:36.281 13828-14796/aabasoft.geomark E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #1

 Process: aabasoft.geomark, PID: 13828
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                  at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:164)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f060011
                at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getResourcePackageName(ResourcesImpl.java:261)
                 at android.content.res.Resources.getResourcePackageName(Resources.java:1949)
                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.oss_licenses.zzc.zza(Unknown Source:10)
                 at com.google.android.gms.internal.oss_licenses.zzc.zza(Unknown Source:12)
                 at com.google.android.gms.oss.licenses.zzb.loadInBackground(Unknown Source:4)
                 at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:307)
                 at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:60)
                 at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:48)
                 at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:141)
                 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: start your activity  from  `postexecute` method in your AsyncTask

Comment: I'm not using any Asyc Task. In an Activity on a button click         `startActivity(new Intent(this, OssLicensesMenuActivity.class));`

Comment: show your intent code

Comment: public void onClick(View v) {

        startActivity(new Intent(this, OssLicensesMenuActivity.class));

    }

Comment: i dont think this error is related to that dependency

Comment: i updated the error with some more details

Comment: My issue is the same as the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688197/oss-license-plugin-crashes-on-starting-osslicensesmenuactivity/51394239#51394239